# spring-ws not serialize object correctly

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I have a problem with serialization of an object into XML and I don't know where is the problem. The serialization of the object in XML looks like the memory of the object serialized. All other object that I serialize are correclty serialized.

On the spring integration tests, the object is serialised correctly. Only when I deploy the app on the weblogic server, it is not serialised corectly. In the weblogic 12 I did not put any special libraries.

Any idea?

Like this the object serialized looks like:

```
 <ns1:Objectives>mypackage.ObjectiveObj@5eba0500</ns1:Objectives>
```

The class that needs to be serialised looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
name = "ObjectiveObj",
propOrder = {"objective"}
)
public class ObjectiveObj {
@XmlElement(
    name = "Objective"
)
protected List<Objective> objective;

public ObjectiveListType() {
}

public List<Objective> getObjective() {
    if (this.objective == null) {
        this.objective = new ArrayList();
    }

    return this.objective;
}
```

}

Edit:
just need to clarify things a bit.
The class is genrated form xsd file using jaxB
spring-ws use that class to marshal it when sending the Soap response.
I dotn know if this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The string `mypackage.ObjectiveObj@5eba0500` in your XML output
is not the memory contents of your object, but it is the
output of its `toString` method.
You got this because in your `ObjectiveObj` class
you didn't implement a `toString()` method of your own,
and therefore you got the `toString()` inherited from
the `java.lang.Object` class

Quoted from [its API doc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)

> `public String toString()`
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the `toString`
> method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.
> The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy
> for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name
> of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@',
> and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.
> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

To fix this you can override this method with your own implementation

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ....;
}
```

##### Edit:

May be you already have an `XmlAdapter<String, ObjectiveObj>` in place,
which in its `marshal` method uses the `toString` method of `ObjectiveObj`.
If you don't have an adapter for `ObjectiveObj` yet, then you should
create one, implement its `marshal` and `unmarshal` methods, and activate
it for `ObjectiveObj` by using the `@XmlTypeAdapter` annotation.

Comment: yes the toString is from Object for sure. But all other clases includding this is generated with jaxb from xsd files. All the other classes are serialised corectly only this one is not, why?

Comment: @DanutClapa See my (very speculative) edit.

Comment: the service is a Soap service, as it says into the title, it use spring-ws to unmarshal the request and marshal the response. That class is generated from the xsd using jaxB. There is nothing done by hand there.